# Javascript to change css

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

How would I go about creating a script that checked if a div was set to any other value than display:none.

I have an image over an accordion, but when I click on an accordion element I want to hide the image over the top.

So say my content was in the form of a class called "accord_content" and my image that is displayed was "image_over". Could i create a script that checked to see if accord_content was shown and if so to hide "image_over"?

```
if ('.accord_content.display !== 'none') {
        image_over.display = 'none')
        }
```

Just a quick try, not to good at javascript so confused at how to complete this

Thanks

New update - This is an extract of the html that i want to check is displayed

```
<h3 class="title">Making the shortlist</h3>
        <div class="accord_content">
        <div class="content_left">

<p>CONTENT</p>

<p>CONTENT>
    </div>
```

Now this is using the jquery accordion ui, so when the page is open class accord_content is display:none,

and when the the h3 is clicked it changes to display:block.

thanks

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but wonder if you are overcomplicating things. Do you actually need to change whole classes of elements or just one? Do you really need to *check* whether an element/class is displayed, given that your code is probably what controls whether it is hidden/displayed?

Comment: hi stuart thanks for your reply, its using the jquery accordion ui, which changes the display of an element when the h3 is clicked. I want to overlay an image and then when an h3 is clicked hide that image. I have tried z index so it pops the image behind the content with no luck

Comment: @DIM3NSION - There is no reference to `.image_over` in your html. If you are using jquery ui accordion you can probably do what you want with pure css or something. Can you share a live example of your accordion somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can do the following:

**Javascript**

```
if ($('.accord_content').css('display') !== 'none') {
    $('.image_over').hide();
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yn39r/1/)**

This will work in the following way. If any `.accord_content` is visible then all `.image_over` are hidden.

Or in native javascript you can do this:

**Javascript**

```
if (document.querySelector('.accord_content').style.display !== 'none') {
    document.querySelector('.image_over').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yn39r/)**

This will get the first instance of `.accord_content` and hide the first `.image_over`. This check will only return false if `display: none` is set to `.accord_content` as an inline `style` attribute and not with css.

You should really post some relevant html in your question. Also a description of how this is to work. If you post a vague question you will get a vague answer. Take the time to post a good question and people will take the time to post a good answer.

Comment: Note that this ignores styles set in CSS. If accord_content is set to display: none in the stylesheet, the .image_over elements will still not be displayed. I'm not clear from the question whether that will be a problem or not.

Comment: perfect, see me edit, im sure this will work just its not at the moment, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (element.style.display !== 'none') {}
```